# spring i18n behavior is different between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, internationalization

I use Spring boot i18n.

In windows, if the chosen locale have not the sentence A, it will use the sentence in messages.properties.

In CentOS, if the choosen locale have not the sentence A, it will use the sentence in messages_en_US.properties first, if the messages_en also have not the sentence, it will use the sentence in messages.properties.

why is it different?

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver clr = new CookieLocaleResolver();//also can use SessionLocaleResolver
    clr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
    return clr;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("locale");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly explain the behavior, but it could be caused by [`ResourceBundle.Control.getFallbackLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#getFallbackLocale(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)). The Javadoc says:

> The default implementation returns the default Locale if the given localeisn't the default one.

So, I suggest to check if the Java default locale makes a difference.